# Some chain rule questions. Answer checks

Tags: calculus

I have these problems and I just wanted to make sure I was doing Chain Rule correctly and that no further simplification was possible:

1. $$y = (2x^3 + 5)^4$$
   $$ so \frac{dy}{dx} = 4(2x^3+5)^3 * 6x^2$$

$$ = 24x^2(2x^3 + 5)^3$$

2. $$f(x) = (5x^6 + 2x^3)^4$$

$$f'(x) = 4(5x^6 + 2x^3)^3 *(30x^5 + 6x^2)$$

3.

$$f(x) = (1 + x + x^2)^{99}$$

$$f'(x) = 99(1 + x + x^2)^{98} * (1 + 2x)$$

4.

$$f(x) = \sqrt{5x + 1}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} * (5x+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} * 5$$
$$\frac{2.5}{\sqrt{5x + 1}}$$

5. I could use some help on this one:

$$f(x) = (2x-3)^4 * (x^2+x+1)^5$$

I started with this:

$$ f'(x) = (2x-3)^4 * 5(x^2+x+1)^4 * (2x+1) + (x^2 +x+1)^5 * 4(2x-3)^3 * 2$$

But how do I simplify from here?

Comment: On number $2$, it should be $(5x^2+2x^3)^3$ and not $(5x^6+2x^3)^3$ so the answer would be  $4(5x^2+2x^3)^3 \cdot(10x^2+6x^2)$ and you should check $3$ again becuse it is totally wrong. On $5$ use the product rule

Comment: You're missing an $^3$ at the first x i your secon line, but it pops up in the third, so you just forgott it. But if you just want to check some easy derivatives, maybe use Wolfram ALpha instead of Stack Exchange.

Comment: sorry, made the appropriate edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was getting too long so I'll post a short answer.

For number $5$, as mentioned in the comments you should use the product rule. Recall that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}g(x)+f(x)\frac{dg(x)}{dx}.$$

Now, set $$\begin{aligned}&f(x)=(2x-3)^4\\&g(x)=(x^2+x+1)^5\end{aligned}$$
and differentiate both (using the chain rule as you did on the previous exercises)

$$\begin{aligned}&\frac{df(x)}{dx}=8(2x-3)^3\\&\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=5(2x+1)(x^2+x+1)^4\end{aligned}$$

so
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left((2x-3)^4(x^2+x+1)^5\right)=8(2x-3)^3(x^2+x+1)^5+5(2x+1)(2x-3)^4(x^2+x+1)^4$$
and by simplifying furthermore, you obtain
$$(2 x-3)^3 \left(x^2+x+1\right)^4 \left(28 x^2-12 x-7\right).$$